# COUNTIF of DATEDIF for calculating if its been 12 months

Tags: excel

I'm trying to calculate between and employee start date and 12 month review for a reward sheet and I can work out the days using `DATEDIF` but I want to use a `list` to set the months for the year so I can check who's 12 month anniversary is coming up.

I'm not asking for the full answer but a bit of guidance would be useful.

Comment: Datedif will do months.  Not sure exactly what you are asking. Could you show some nock up data and expected output.

Comment: Can you just use `=Month([cell reference to start date])` to get the month of the review?

Comment: Assuming start date is in cell A1, could you use the `DATE` function to work out the date of the 12 month review - i.e. `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)`? Then `DATEDIF` would let you see how many days away that is from, say, the current date.